# Locked out of Google Cloud server because of sshd.conf misconfiguration

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

While trying to solve another issue with connection problems to our servers, I thought to solve the problem by setting the MaxConnections and MaxStartups to my sshd.conf

When restarting ssh everything seemed fine, but this morning I found out that our Jenkins server didn't connect to any of the dev servers. So I tried logging into the system, finding out that I cannot log in to any of our dev servers anymore.

Looks like I made a F#@$up in the sshd.conf and created a lockout for all the dev servers.

When trying to login I get an "port 22: Connection refused" error.

Is there any other way to get into the systems without having to connect every disk to another server to adjust the sshd.conf??

Comment: Did you try restarting the VM?

Comment: Off course I did, but thanks for thinking with me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available for recovery in this situation:

1. Use the [interactive serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console). This requires advanced preparation.
2. Add a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to fix the file, and then reboot to trigger the script.
3. Shutdown the instance, attach the disk to a recovery instance, use the recovery instance to mount the disk and fix the file, then detatch the disk and recreate the instance using the fixed disk. (you can also do this from a snapshot for added safety).